# Why aren't static template fields initialized unless used?

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [(static initialization/template instantiation) problems with factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851991/static-initialization-template-instantiation-problems-with-factory-pattern)
> [trying to force static object initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549714/trying-to-force-static-object-initialization)

#### EDIT: There is a duplicate of this but I'll leave this up as I personally had trouble finding it. In addition here's the answer that helped me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2852234/673730

Assume the following class:

```
template<class X>
struct A
{
   static bool x;
   static bool foo()
   {
      cout << "here";
      return true;
   }
};

template<class X>
bool A<X>::x = A<X>::foo();
```

I would have assumed that when I specialize `A`, the static field `x` would get initialized. However, the following:

```
A<int> a;
//no output
```

doesn't result in a call to `foo`. If I try to access the member, the behavior is as expected:

```
A<int> a;
bool b = a.x;
//output: here
```

EDIT: **How can I make sure `A::x` is initialized without accessing it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This think is the reference(14.7.1.2) :

Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist; in particular, the initialization (and any associated side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.

```
template<class X, bool y>
struct A
{
    static cosnt bool x = y;
    static bool foo()
    {
       cout << "here";
       return true;
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 12):

If a template is *implicitly* specialised by virtue of being instantiated, then only those members that are actually referred to are instantiated.

Contrast this with *explicit* class template instantiation (`template struct A<int>;`), which instantiates and creates code for *all* members. (You can also instantiate only specific members individually: `template bool A<int>::x;`.)