# Ensuring a static member of a class is constructed

Tags: c++, c++11, static

Consider the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Printer{
    Printer(){
        std::cout << "Created\n";
    }
};

template<class Derived>
struct InitPrinter{
    static Printer p;
};

template<class Derived>
Printer InitPrinter<Derived>::p;


struct MyClass:InitPrinter<MyClass>{
     MyClass(){}

};

// Uncomment line below to print out created
//auto& p = MyClass::p;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that this would print out "Created", however, it does not print out anything (tested with MSVC and with ideone gcc c++11). Is this a compiler implementation issue, or is this behavior supported by the standard? If the commented out line is uncommented then it prints out as expected. Is there any way to the `static Printer p` to be instantiated without requiring either changes to MyClass or extra statements like the `auto& p = MyClass::p`?

The reason I am interested in this is I am looking to have create a templated base class, that will run some code at startup when it is derived from.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18600034/420683

Comment: [temp.inst]/10 "An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, [...] or a static data member of a class template that does not require instantiation." And deriving from a class template specialization does not require instantiating (the definition of) its static data members.

Comment: @DyP why this is not an answer?

Comment: @AlexanderB Because it's short and I'm lazy? :P

Comment: I got it working by changing auto& p to Printer p, but I guess that is not what you wanted :P

Comment: @DyP Lazy enough to read the question and look up the relevant specification...

Comment: Related / solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6420985/420683 duplicate (of duplicates): http://stackoverflow.com/q/10333871/420683

Comment: @DyP Looking at the links you provided, it still looks like there is no standard guaranteed way to do what I want. Thanks for looking this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appropriate quote is [temp.inst]/2

> Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly
>   specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced
>   in a context that requires the member definition to exist; **in particular, the initialization (and any associated
>   side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way
>   that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.**

emphasis mine.

---

There's also [temp.inst]/1

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit
>   instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions or default arguments, of the class member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members and member templates [...]

and [temp.inst]/10

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, [...] or a static data member of a class template that does not require instantiation.